# Как расположить элементы списка в два столбика?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как расположить элементы списка в два столбика? По пять элементов в одном столбике.
Как это можно реализовать?

```css
.wrap{
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>Один</li>
    <li>Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
    <li>Пять</li>
    <li>Шесть</li>
    <li>Семь</li>
    <li>Восемь</li>
    <li>Девять</li>
    <li>Десять</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrap{
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
ul{
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>Один</li>
    <li>Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
    <li>Пять</li>
    <li>Шесть</li>
    <li>Семь</li>
    <li>Восемь</li>
    <li>Девять</li>
    <li>Десять</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: @Vearo нормальная поддержка

Comment: Хорошо, пользуйтесь на здоровье)

Comment: @Vearo так и делаю

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrap{
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>Один</li>
    <li>Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
    <li>Пять</li>
    <li>Шесть</li>
    <li>Семь</li>
    <li>Восемь</li>
    <li>Девять</li>
    <li>Десять</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
ul{
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul.flex-direction-column{
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 120px;
}

li{
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>Один</li>
    <li>Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
    <li>Пять</li>
    <li>Шесть</li>
    <li>Семь</li>
    <li>Восемь</li>
    <li>Девять</li>
    <li>Десять</li>
    <li>Одинадцать</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="flex-direction-column">
    <li>Один</li>
    <li>Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
    <li>Пять</li>
    <li>Шесть</li>
    <li>Семь</li>
    <li>Восемь</li>
    <li>Девять</li>
    <li>Десять</li>
    <li>Одинадцать</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```